# css horizontal nav menu float right, vertical sub-menus not aligned with main menu

Tags: css, menu, nav

I have created a horizontal nav menu in css, floated left. It works fine.

When I change the float to right (and reverse the order of top level li's), everything is fine except that the sub-menus are shifted left a bit (and so don't align vertically with the top-level menu items).

I tried changing the left command in `li:hover > .nav`, but that didn't help.  Can anyone see what needs to change to get vertical alignment of the top level nav items and the items in the sub-menus?

Thanks.

**My CSS is:**

```
#nav, .nav, #nav .nav li { 
    margin:0px; 
    padding:0px; 
}

#nav li {
    float:right; 
    display:inline; 
    cursor:pointer; 
    list-style:none; 
    padding:10px 30px 10px 30px; 
    border:1px #000 solid;  
    position:relative;
    background: #990000;
}

#nav li ul.first {
    left:-1px; 
    top:100%;
}

li, li a {
    color:#fff; 
    text-decoration:none;
}

#nav .nav li { 
    width:100%; 
    text-indent:10px; 
    line-height:30px; 
    margin-right:10px; 
    border-top:1px #000 solid; 
    border-bottom:1px #000 solid;
    border-left:none; 
    border-right:none; 
    background:#990000;
}

#nav li a {
    display:block; 
    width:inherit; 
    height:inherit;
}

ul.nav { 
    display:none; 
}

#nav li:hover > a, #nav li:hover { 
    color:#990000; 
    background:#fff; 
}

li:hover > .nav { 
    display:block; 
    position:absolute; 
    width:200px; 
    top:-2px; 
    left:50%; 
    z-index:1000; 
    border:1px #000 solid; 
}

li:hover { 
    position:relative; 
    z-index:2000; 
}

#basic li {
    color:#000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When switching from `float: left` to `float: right`, did you exchange all left-related properties to right and right to left?

Examples:

- replacing `margin-left` by `margin-right`
- exchanging values. `margin 1px 2px 3px 4px` becomes `margin 1px 4px 3px 2px`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to trying the answer above, you could bump the sub menus over using `position:relative` and either the right or left properties. They will move the menus however many pixels you specify relative to the position they are falling naturally.